# jQuery substr() multi select values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a:

```
$('#product_category  > option:selected').each(function()
```

and append it to some box's with

```
.append(<div>'+$(this).text()+'</div>);
```

but i want to substr the text to only show 9 chars. and if the length is bigger then 9 then write the first 9 and +"..."

ive tryed:

```
    $('#product_category  > option:selected').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text(); 
    if(text.val().length > 8)
    {
        text = text.substr(0,9)+"...";
    }

    $('#confirm-category').append('<div class="alert alert-success">'+text+'</div>');    
});
```

but its not working :/

i'll be happy for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your if condition

```
if(text.val().length > 8)
```

to

```
if(text.length > 8)
```

you don't need `val()` there since you already have its text `text()`.

```
var text = $(this).text();  //<---here
```

Answer (score 0):

text variable is not jquery object so you can write it without val();

```
$('#product_category  > option:selected').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text(); 
    if(text.length > 8)
    {
        text = text.substr(0,9)+"...";
    }

    $('#confirm-category').append('<div class="alert alert-success">'+text+'</div>');    
});
```